# Creating Vertical Tabs loading visuals from an exterior JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering how to get my Vertical tabs to show visuals I created on an alternate page. The tabs are styled, and the CSS is omitted because of the length. My html file is **test.html** and the alternate file is **App.js**. When I click on the tab, I want to show the visuals created in **App.js** I have tested the visuals to make sure they work. But when I click the tab, nothing shows. It is like clicking a button with nothing attached to it. Nothing happens.

How can I add in the visuals into the tabs to make them show?

Code of test.html Page(I left out my CSS link. CSS works to align):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-App="App">
    <div id="container" style="padding-top: 20px" ng-controller="AppController">
    <div id="tab">
       <button class="tablink" onclick="show1()">Visual 1</button>
    </div>

    <div id="visual1" ng-show"display1">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="App.js"></script>
       <div id="testdash">
         <div id="filter1"></div>
         <div id="chart1"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js page:

```
var app = angular.module('App',);
 app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $http, $ace) {
       $scope.show1 = function() {
        if ($scope.display1 == false) {
            getCurrVis1();
            $scope.display1 = true;   }
        else {
            $scope.display1 = false;  }     
        }

    function getCurrVis1() { 
            var req = { method: 'POST',
                        url: "test.tsv" 
            }
            $http(req).success(function(js) {
                var data = js;
                drawChart1(data); 
            })
    }

    function drawChart1(data) {
        //creates data table
        var table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var data = data;
        console.log(data);
        var dataRows = data.split("\n");
        var headers = dataRows[0].split('\t');
        table.addColumn('string', headers[0]); 
        table.addColumn('number', headers[1]);
        table.addColumn('string', headers[2]);
        var rs = [];

        for (var x=1; x<(dataRows.length); x++) {
            var cols = dataRows[x].split('\t');
            var row = [];
            row.push(cols[0]);           
            row.push(parseInt(cols[1]));
            row.push(cols[2]);
            rs.push(row);
        }

        table.addRows(rs);

        // Create a dashboard to bind a filter to the chart
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('testdash'));

        var filter1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter1',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnIndex': 0,
                'ui': { 
                    'label': 'Filter:',
                    'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowStacked',
                    'allowTyping': false,
                    'allowMultiple':true,}
            }
        });

        //Sets chart, and chart options
        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    'chartType': 'PieChart',
                    'containerId': 'chart1',
                    'options': { 'left': '25%',
                        'height': '80%',
                        'width': '80%' ,
                        'width':800,
                        'height':600,
                        'pieSliceText': 'value'},
                    'view': { 'columns': [0,1]}
        });

        dashboard.bind(filter1, chart);
        dashboard.draw(table);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Slight change to the **HTML** page and we are good to go! 
Here is the code for the working sample:

```
<html>
<body>   
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="functionname(event, 'DIVID') ng-click="show1()">TabName</button>
</div>

<div id="DIVID" class="tabcontent">
<h3>Content1</h3>
    <div id="panel1" ng-show="display5">   <!-- div id for panels and down...-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="App.js"></script>
            <div id = "test.js">
                <div id = "filter1"></div>
                <div id = "chart1" align = "center"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

function functionname(value1, value2) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(value2).style.display = "block";
    value1.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```